# How to convert uint to bool array?

Tags: c#, bit, uint

for example

```
uint <- 1
```

I want to get

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

if

```
uint <- 8
```

get it

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Just format by bit , How can I do?

Comment: `var binaryString = Convert.ToString(someInteger, 2)` The second argument specifies base 2 a.k.a binary..

Comment: And at which point did you fail when you tried? And `0` and `1` are no `bool` values, please be specific about your requirements, do you want a `boo[]` or a string of ones and zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        uint x = 1;
        List<bool> result = new List<bool>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
        {
            bool isBitSet = ((x >> i) & 0x01) > 0;
            result.Add(isBitSet);
        }       
    }
}
```

Note that this will push the lsbit first.

Answer (score 2):

You can try *Linq* for this:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  uint source = 8;

  int[] result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, sizeof(uint) * 8)
    .Reverse()
    .Select(i => (source & (1 << i)) == 0 ? 0 : 1)
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(" ", result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

If you want `bool[] result` the query can be

```
  bool[] result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, sizeof(uint) * 8)
    .Reverse()
    .Select(i => (source & (1 << i)) != 0)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: gotta love Linq :-)

Answer (score 1):

And another option:
Use [`Convert.ToString(Int64, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int64_System_Int32_) to create the binary representation of the `uint` value (a [built in implicit conversion from `UInt32` to `Int64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions) exists, so no problem there).
Then add the leading zeros using string's [`PadLeft(int, char)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_PadLeft_System_Int32_System_Char_)
Then use `Select` to convert the chars to boolean values - and finally, `ToArray()`:

```
static bool[] To32WithSpaces(uint number)
{
    return Convert.ToString(number, 2)
        .PadLeft(32, '0')
        .Select(c => c=='1')
        .ToArray();
}
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>rextester</kbd>](https://rextester.com/IGVXO67141)